# Why combined code is not working for data.table R, though it works as an individual line of code

Tags: r, data.table

I am not understanding why data.table behaving differently every time I add chaining in data.table in R. Here is my code

```
DT_Trends_Data_3<-copy(DT_Trends_Data_2)  #nothing wrong here
```

It generates an error when I execute below query

```
Step 0

DT_Trends_Data_4<-DT_Trends_Data_3[,':='(s_d=sd(last_seen_hour_alerts), m_n=mean(last_seen_hour_alerts),limits = m_n + s_d,flag=ifelse(last_seen_hour_alerts>limits,"Yes","No")),by=.(customer,location_id)]

Error in `[.data.table`(DT_Trends_Data_3, , `:=`(s_d = sd(last_seen_hour_alets),  : 
 ​object 'm_n
```

However, when I run above script step by step as given below, it works without any issue

```
Step 1

DT_Trends_Data_4<-DT_Trends_Data_3[,':='(s_d=sd(last_seen_hour_alerts)),by=.(customer,location_id)]       


Step 2 

DT_Trends_Data_4<-DT_Trends_Data_3[,':='(s_d=sd(last_seen_hour_alerts), m_n=mean(last_seen_hour_alerts)),by=.(customer,location_id)]


Step 3 

DT_Trends_Data_4<-DT_Trends_Data_3[,':='(s_d=sd(last_seen_hour_alerts), m_n=mean(last_seen_hour_alerts),limits = m_n + s_d),by=.(customer,location_id)]

Step 4 

DT_Trends_Data_4<-DT_Trends_Data_3[,':='(s_d=sd(last_seen_hour_alerts), m_n=mean(last_seen_hour_alerts),limits = m_n + s_d,flag=ifelse(last_seen_hour_alerts>limits,"Yes","No")),by=.(customer,location_id)]
```

After executing step 1 to step 4 , now if I run step 0 query (consolidated/combined query), it runs without any issue. And again, if I try executing step 0 query as a starting, it throws an error as described in step 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are trying to call the m_n in the limits variable creation, while this variable is defined prior but still doesn't exist, when you do it step wise step, the variable was created and hence it works

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar like this:

As I have mentioned in comments, you are trying to use the variable `m_n` for the creation of `limits`, since the variable is yet to be created (although defined before limits variable,it is yet to be created) hence it throws the error, one work around could be using something like below(which involves chaining). When you try it step by step, the variable m_n gets created and readily available for next step that is why step wise execution works.

Using `iris` dataset and converting it to `data.table` using

```
iris1 <- copy(iris)
setDT(iris1)
iris1[,temp:=mean(Sepal.Length), by=Species][,new_temp:=mean(abs(Sepal.Length-temp)), by=Species][,temp:=NULL]
```

**Output**:

```
> head(ir)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_temp
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  0.27072
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  0.27072
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  0.27072
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  0.27072
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  0.27072
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  0.27072
```

Answer (score 1):

`n_m` and `s_d` are not defined yet when `limits` are being evaluated and that is why there is an error. Here is how you can fix it:

```
DT_Trends_Data_3[, ':=' (s_d = {s_d <- sd(last_seen_hour_alerts)},
        m_ n = {m_n <- mean(last_seen_hour_alerts)},
        limits = {limits <- m_n + s_d},
        flag = ifelse(last_seen_hour_alerts>limits,"Yes","No")),
    by=.(customer,location_id)]
```

or more clearly:

```
DT_Trends_Data_3[, c("s_d", "m_n", "limits", "flag") := {
    s_d <- sd(last_seen_hour_alerts) 
    m_n <- mean(last_seen_hour_alerts)
    limits <- m_n + s_d
    flag <- ifelse(last_seen_hour_alerts>limits,"Yes","No")
    .(s_d, m_n, limits, flag)
}, by=.(customer,location_id)]
```